# 2022 French HTTPS Encryption Compliance Requirements?

Tags: ios, encryption, mobile, https, appstore-approval

I would like to know from folks with HTTPS apps distributed in France if its still required to submit documents to the French Gov. ?

Ive started to translate/fill them out but theyre super difficult to understand - hopefully I can just stop working on this if the iOS Console is out of date with the real world as per usual.

Thanks for your answers and hopefully others will find them useful as well

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No. Just add the **ITSAppUsesNonExemptEncryption** key to your app’s Info.plist file with a Boolean value that indicates whether your app uses encryption. Set the value to NO if your app—including any third-party libraries it links against—doesn’t use encryption, or if it only uses forms of encryption that are exempt from export compliance documentation requirements. Otherwise, set it to YES.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/complying_with_encryption_export_regulations